# Prior Art Challenge to application US20160203808

Tags: prior-art-request, us20160203808

In reference to the patent: [US20160203808](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160203808A1/en)

PRIOR ART to this "invention" is available for review.  ORIGINAL collections  have been introduced to manufacturers for distribution, for this concept.  Distribution of marketing in 2006, and License negotiations in 2012.

Comment: Do you have any record of your prior art beeing known to the public or used in public before the filing date of the application?

Comment: Does "available for review" mean you will not be posting it here?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide the prior art you are already familiar with.

Comment: I did find this: http://www.bellbottombeverageware.com. This company is from Houston, TX as is the inventor so it seems likely they are related.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that, looks like that the glass that Eric found, maybe was available on the market already before the priority date.
[image]

Comment: Nice use of Google!

Answer (score 0):

I did find this: [bellbottombeverageware.com](http://bellbottombeverageware.com). This company is from Houston, TX as is the inventor so it seems likely they are related. I did a Google image search and found this [page with a similar product](http://dealers.bigmouthinc.com/BMT/Drinking-Stuff/Ring-for-Wine-Glass).

[image]

There is no indication when this product went on the market, but you might be able to track down the manufacturer and ask.

Answer (score 0):

[US6066021A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6066021A/) Glass drinking vessel with a bottom ornament. Published on 2000-05-23.
[image]

Comment: Nice find, but I'm not sure this is prior art since it doesn't teach a bell feature.